# Need support LM2733 boost converter

Tags: boost

i working on 3W DC to DC boos converter using LM2733YMF IC

Specs are-
Vin- 12V
Vout- 36V, 100mA
FSW- 600KHz

Schematic and components selected as per WEBENCH design tool.
find attached file

[image]
board work fine without load all parameters ok like SW, FB, SHDN, VIN.

but when i test with load suddenly after suppy turning ON IC get damage due to spike at SW pin.

Any suggetion..?

Comment: Probably the ringing at SW is exceeding 40V. Show your setup with complete schematic and part values.

Comment: hi rohat thanks, schematic attached pls see.. for ringing at SW pin a tryingto use RC snubber but same results

Comment: I see the schematic but the diode's P/N is missing. We can't estimate what diode you used. TI Webench suggests **CD214A-B150LF** but you may not have this at hand. So maybe you've put an alternative and maybe it's slow. Who knows? That's why I said *"complete schematic with part values"*. Also, you still didn't show the setup i.e. how you hooked up the circuit. Please note that the IC does not have an on-board snubber for the internal NMOS, so the performance depends on the layout. You may expect the SW node voltage to be 30.5V but it can jump to as high as 50+V.

Comment: Are you testing it with a load at all times?

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: Show layout. Show oscillogram of said spike at SW pin.

Comment: @ocrdu load is LED 36V, 100mA

Comment: @Andyaka yes without load all parameter ok but with load isnt work

Comment: @RohatKılıç thanks dear i used diode ES1J which already available with me but i think doesnt matter diode due to higher rating

Answer (score 0):

If the coil is physically too small and it saturates with the load on, the SW can be damaged from the high current. Without load the coil doesn't saturate because of the short switch on time.
If the diode is slow then the spike without load is higher and more risk of damage, so it's not likely the diode.